# while running sample C2DM app crashes while registering to c2dm server and receiving push notification

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm trying to run c2dm sample applications like jumpnote, [bigdaddy](http://bigdaddy-io.appspot.com/) app in my android rooted 3.0 gtab wifi model, while runing bigdaddy google io sample app while registering to c2dm server and receiving push notification I'm getting runtime error and application crashes!!!!

Note: c2dm server registrations successful!
C2DM apps does't works on rooted android devices? 
I tested in *noon rooted* phone able to receive c2dm message but crashes while registering the user to c2dm service, but registration successful!!

> *Problem is demo code/app crashes in rooted viewsonic gtab while C2DM registering, receiving messages , but almost works correctly in non rooted devices!*

**app, code Links:** [Google IO demo APP](http://bigdaddy-io.appspot.com/),    [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/#svn/trunk/DemoFiles)

[image: C2DM bigdaddy google io app error]

Log:

```
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139): Activity Manager Crash
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null intent at index 0
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3946)
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:799)
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1521)
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
06-03 09:08:32.633: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.bigdaddy.UPDATE_UI (has extras) } in com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity$1@40597d28
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:725)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null intent at index 0
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:2356)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at com.bigdaddy.Util.generateNotification(Util.java:100)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity$1.onReceive(BigDaddyActivity.java:76)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:716)
06-03 09:08:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(16339):    ... 9 more
06-03 09:08:32.643: W/ActivityManager(1139):   Force finishing activity com.bigdaddy/.BigDaddyActivity
06-03 09:08:33.153: W/ActivityManager(1139): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40856d98 com.bigdaddy/.BigDaddyActivity}
06-03 09:10:10.623: E/InputDispatcher(1139): channel '41959420 com.bigdaddy/com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-03 09:10:10.633: E/InputDispatcher(1139): channel '41959420 com.bigdaddy/com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-03 09:10:10.653: I/WindowManager(1139): WIN DEATH: Window{41959420 com.bigdaddy/com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity paused=false}
06-03 09:10:10.663: I/WindowManager(1139): WINDOW DIED Window{41959420 com.bigdaddy/com.bigdaddy.BigDaddyActivity paused=false}
06-03 09:10:10.703: W/InputManagerService(1139): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 16339 uid 10130
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139): Activity Manager Crash
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null intent at index 0
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3946)
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:799)
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1521)
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
06-03 09:10:33.774: E/ActivityManager(1139):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-03 09:10:33.823: W/dalvikvm(16480): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[gwtc2dm@gmail.com]
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null intent at index 0
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:2356)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at com.bigdaddy.Util.generateNotification(Util.java:100)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at com.bigdaddy.MessageDisplay.displayMessage(MessageDisplay.java:44)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at com.bigdaddy.C2DMReceiver.onMessage(C2DMReceiver.java:82)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.onHandleIntent(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:112)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-03 09:10:33.873: E/AndroidRuntime(16480):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-03 09:10:35.253: W/GTalkService(1458): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.bigdaddy] (has extras) }
06-03 09:10:35.253: W/ActivityManager(1139): Unable to launch app com.bigdaddy/10130 for broadcast Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.bigdaddy] (has extras) }: process is bad
06-03 09:10:35.253: W/ActivityManager(1139): finishReceiver called but none active
```

Comment: what is BigDaddyActivity.java:76?
I think we can help you only if we can see your part of the code where your app crash.

Comment: yes vince is right. please post some code too... or the link from where you copied...

Comment: @KKD, Vince thanks!,Updated the demo app, code links,screen-shot.